# Не срабатывает проверка isdigit()

Tags: c

Весь код корректно работает, кроме условия в 27 строке, после которой крашится программа. Если её исключить - программа прекрасно работает. Что неправильно?

```
#include <stdio.h>              
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()

{
    char a1[256], b1[256], c1[256];
    signed int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    double p, s;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    printf("Здравствуйте!\n Введите три стороны треугольника: \n");
    //scanf("%c %c %c", &a1, &b1, &c1);
    //printf("%c,%c,%c", a1, b1, c1);
    fgets(a1, 256, stdin);
    fgets(b1, 256, stdin);
    fgets(c1, 256, stdin);
    /*a = atoi(a1);
    b = atoi(b1);
    c = atoi(c1);
    printf("%d,%d,%d", a, b, c);*/

//Зловещая строчка
    if (isdigit(a1) == 0 || isdigit(b1) == 0 || isdigit(c1) == 0) { printf("\nВведены некорректные данные!\n"); }
    else
    {
        a = atoi(a1);
        b = atoi(b1);
        c = atoi(c1);
        if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0) { printf("\nТреугольник не существует, либо введены некорректные данные. \n"); }
        else if ((a + b) > c && (b + c) > a && (c + a) > b)
        {
            p = (a + b + c) * 0.5; //Полупериметр 
            s = sqrt(p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)); //Формула Герона
            printf("\nПлощадь треугольника равна %f.\n", s);
        }
        else
        {
            { printf("\nТреугольник не существует. \n"); }
        }
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: isdigit проверяет один символ. А Вы пытаетесь передать туда целую строку.

Comment: @KoVadim, в случае одного символа та же проблема.

Тогда можно только посимвольную проверку делать(цифра/не цифра)?

Не хочу велосипед делать просто.

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать sscanf, он может прочитать число с строки. А сама функция возвращает кол-во обработанных символов. Сравнив его с длинной строки, можно сделать вывод, правильно ли были введены данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `isdigit` имеет следующее объявление

```
int isdigit(int c);
```

То есть ее второй праметр имеет тип `int`.

Вы же в качестве аргумента передаете выражение, имеющее тип `char *`

```
char a1[256], b1[256], c1[256];
^^^^^^^^^^^^
//...
if (isdigit(a1) == 0 || isdigit(b1) == 0 || isdigit(c1) == 0) { //...
           ^^^
```

Если вы хотите проверить, является ли первый символ каждого из массивов цифрой, то вам следует записать

```
if (isdigit(( unsigned char )*a1) == 0 || isdigit(( unsigned char )*b1) == 0 || isdigit(( unsigned char )*c1) == 0) { //...
```

Либо в цикле проверить каждый из символов массивов.

Хотя проще было бы использовать функцию `strtol` к каждому из массивов и посмотреть результат ее выполнения.

И для ввода чисел достаточно использовать функцию `scanf`. Нет необходимости использовать `fgets`

Например,

```
signed int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

//...

if ( scanf( "%d %d %d", a, b, c ) != 3 )
{
    //  error message
}
else
{
    // calculate results
}
```

И функцию `main` без параметров в C следует объявлять как

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: Для чего использовать функцию isdigit для типа int?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Я не понял вашего вопроса. В принципе вы могли бы ее dvtcnt с fgets вообще не использовать, а использовать scanf.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Функция имеет тип параметра int, но используется для объектов типа unsigned char.

Comment: По комментариям в коде видно, что я пытался работать со scanf только с 1 символом(char a1,b1,c1), но программа всеравно падала. Я не пойму почему.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Смотрите мой обновленный ответ, в котором я показал, как бы вы  могли использовать scanf.

Comment: Правильно понял, что если введут не цифру, то просто сработает в if?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Если введете некорректный символ, то результат выполнения функции не будет равен 3. Функция возвращает число корректно введенных данных либо EOF.

Comment: Вы гений, это именно то, что я хотел. Спасибо!!!

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Я рад, что я помог вам.:)

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, к Вам в подмастерье можно попасть?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Я трактую это слово как в википедии.